# Why would a white film form on cutlery but not glassware in a dishwasher?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

An odd effect I notice is that I when wash dishes in a commercial dishwasher there is a white film left behind on steel cutlery but not on the glassware, which appears to have no residue. Why would this occur?

I know that the local tap water has high salt content, but if the residue is indeed the salt, why would it preferentially coat the cutlery but not the glasses and dishes?

The cleansers being used are standard commercial liquid detergents and a rinse aid.

Comment: At a guess, the white film is *not* corrosion of the metal cutlery, but salt adhering to it. Experimentally increase the amount of rinse aid used, to see if that helps. As to *why* more rinse aid might be needed for metal than glass, glass is more easily *wetted* by water than metals such as stainless steel. If it works, please let me know and I'll make my educated guess an "answer" :-)

Comment: I suspect this is coming from oils and fats in the steel cutlery (as a result of hard water forming a film precipitated soaps). Certainly, glasses will not have oil or oily products. As a control test, put washed and clean steel dishes and see if a white film is still there. These second reason could be the fact that water jets in the dishwasher are not reaching the steel cutlery properly with full force. You could try changing the way you put dishes, there could be physical blockages.

Comment: @AChem Are you suggesting there is oil inside the steel itself?

Comment: @ShakaBoom, No, oils/fats from food. Why don't you post a picture? A picture is worth a 1000 words :-)